# Mojave 10.14.4 broke something in file system

Tags: mojave

After updating Mojave to 10.14.4 two days ago I've got some weird bugs with working with files. Finder doesn't see pictures created by Photoshop. Webpack-dev-server doesn't see changes in files. What happened? How to roll back to version 10.14.3?

Comment: Upgrades often show that a database or data set were corrupt since it tries to upgrade them or just that it writes a bunch of new files. Rolling back might even make things worse. Want to attack how to troubleshoot this in general and not mix up a roll back? (Since there isn’t a roll back - you would wipe and reinstall)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I try when this kind of thing happens is to re-boot into Safe mode, then re-boot normally.

I find these aberrations don't last, especially after performing the above.  Sometimes you can re-install the update to cure it.